# Two same images displayed at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I am using Fabric js to do image manupulation drag, resize and merge images onto the one image onto the canvas but it shows one bug, i.e when I upload the image it displays two same images at a time, while i need only one.

Please help me to solve this issue.

My code is:

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imageCanvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(240,240,240)'
});

var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
                scaleX: 0.2,
                scaleY: 0.2
            })
            canvas.add(imgInstance);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that one of your images you see is an image element and the other is a canvas element can you check that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I checked it but there is no issue.

Comment: Can you provide the rendered html and or the normal html

Comment: <canvas id="imageCanvas" width="500" height="240"></canvas>
 <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" /> This is my render html

Comment: And both images are contained within the canvas?

Comment: Yes , both image and same image from single browse.